# How to keep checkbox ticked on reload page using value from searchParams

Tags: reactjs

My component looks like this

```
function FilterDiscounts({ discount, handleDiscounts }) {
    const discountsList = Array.from({ length: 9 }, (_, index) => (index + 1) * 10);
    const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false)
    // const [queryParams] = useSearchParams();
    // const discountFromQueryParams = queryParams.get('discount')

    const handleChange = (discountValue) => {
        if(isChecked && discount === discountValue) {
            setIsChecked(false)
            handleDiscounts(null)
        } else {
            setIsChecked(true)
            handleDiscounts(discountValue)
        }
    }

    return (
        <Row>
            <h6>DISCOUNT RANGE</h6>
            {
                discountsList.map((discountOption, index) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={index} className="filter-type">
                            <input
                                type="checkbox"
                                checked={discountOption === discount}
                                onChange={() => handleChange(discountOption)}
                            />
                            <div className="filter-item">{discountOption}% and above</div>
                        </div>
                    )
                })
            }
        </Row>
    );
}
```

I get the `discount` value from queryParams as i've commented at top. 
I tried adding this line

```
checked={discountOption === discountFromQueryParams || discountOption === discount}
```

in input field but it does not retain `checked` state of a particular discount value on reload. However, in queryParams, this value will be there on reload also.

How can i keep the checkbox checked on reload here ?

Comment: most likely the `discountFromQueryParams` is returned with special characters or as an array. console.log it and compare to console.log of discountOption to validate that both strings are for sure identical. If they are, please provide them in the post and Tag me in the comments and I will take a closer look

Comment: @Lith , the `typeof(discountFromQueryParams) is string` and `typeof(discountOption) is Number`. I think this is why it was not getting checked.

Comment: if discountOption is a number then yes that would cause an issue as `===` checks for both value and type. You can solve this by either doing `==` (ignoring types) OR comvering the string into a number or number into a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with types of `discountOption` - `Number` and `discountFromQueryParams` - `string` and i was using `===` operator.

Changed these few lines here to

```
const discountFromQueryParams = Number(queryParams.get('discount'))
...
if((isChecked && discountValue === discount) || (discountValue === discountFromQueryParams)) { ... }
...
checked={discountOption === discountFromQueryParams || discountOption === discount}
```